# Creating a new gallery folder in Android on first app launch

Tags: android

I'm trying to make it so when a user launches the app for the first time, a new folder is created within the Gallery section of the phone and ISN'T duplicated every time the app is launched. I've looked through some answers on here but most are either confusing or out-of-date. Please can somebody help?

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "MyNewFolderName" + File.separator)
};
```

I have also included this line in AndroidManifext.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: this issue is in Android 6?

Comment: I'm testing on 5.1.1

Comment: Beyond Budius' answer, note that the directory itself may not show up in file explorers for some time, particularly while the directory is empty, due to the way [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) works. However, the directory will exist, and you can start putting images there.

Comment: @CommonsWare - is there a quick way to find out that it has created it without looking in the gallery?

Comment: @blueprintChris: The file browser in the Android Device Monitor should show the directory immediately (get to that from Tools > Android from the Android Studio main menu). Or, use `adb shell` to get at the command line shell in the device or emulator and poke around external storage that way. Both of those work off the filesystem, not the `MediaStore`, and so your new directory should be visible immediately.

Comment: @CommonsWare - forgive me for being a n00b but I'm looking at the Device Monitor now and can't see 'storage/emulated/0' (which is where the picture gallery is located according to the details on the pictures) but can only see 'storage/emulated/legacy'

Comment: The paths reported in the code may vary from the paths reported in the tools, in part because Android supports multiple user accounts, each of which gets a separate spot on the filesystem for internal and external storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were so so close to the answer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    // this line creates reference to a folder that might or not exist, but does not create
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "MyNewFolderName" + File.separator)
    root.mkdirs(); // this line creates the folder
};
```

also, if you're running that on Marshmallow (android 6), you have to first ask permission to write to storage, you can read here about asking permission http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: I'm assuming that this will only create it once and only once?